# Eclipse Subversion Repository Import Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm having an issue with my Eclipse Subversion Repository.  Obviously enough, I'm working on a project in which our teams most current additions are being uploaded to the repository.  I imported a folder from our repository named "Test", and later deleted it... Now I'm having issues importing the same folder.  When trying to import I get the following error:

> 'SVN Import' has encountered a problem.
>
> ```
> org.apache.subverison.javahl.ClientException:  The process cannot access the file  because another process has locked a portion of the file.
> svn: Can't read file 'C:\Users\Submersed\workspace\.metadata\.lock': The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.  
>
> org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.  
> svn: Can't read file 'C:\Users\Submersed\workspace\.metadata\.lock': The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.
> ```

I've tried deleting the `.metadata\.lock` file, and I've tried reinstalling eclipse and subversion entirely.  I have been able to import the data to an external drive, but it's a hassle to not be able to just store it on my local drive.

If anyone has an idea as to what the issue may be, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't check in the whole workspace. You should only check in the projects without the meta data and get the workspace generated. You could generate the project configuration with tools like [maven](http://maven.apache.org) and [Maven to Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/). So you could avoid problems with differnent paths, etc.

If you however have to check in the whole workspace use command line tools. Eclipse holds the lock file while your workspace is open, so you cannot overwrite that file while eclipse has opened it.